# WDS (Wireless Distribution System) is not working

Tags: networking, wds

I have a D-Link DI-524 as a main router (192.168.0.1) connected to the Internet and a second router (192.168.0.2), a TP-Link TL-WR841N, with WDS enabled and correctly configured to "join" with the D-Link.

After I connect a laptop via wireless (192.168.0.100) to the TP-Link, both work well but with the laptop I can't go to the Internet.

It seems as if WDS is not working.

With the laptop I can only ping the TP-Link (the D-Link or other LAN computers are not responding).

What's the problem? Does the D-Link also need to have WDS enabled?

Answer (score 2):

In order for WDS to work you need to enable it on both APs (and must be supported by both APs)

Answer (score 0):

can you check the tp-link status windows, there is WAN section what it says?

if possible please fallow this steps it may work; network->Wan-> Connection type Static and ip adress pick 192.168.2.50 ( differen than your local lan) and subnet 255.255.255.0 default gateway 192.168.0.1 (thath is your d-link with internet) and save config. and go to DHCP menu in tplink and disable dhcp server and there is a default gateway config aswell please put the same there 192.168.0.1 and save & reboot try again if your laptop connects properly

Answer (score 0):

Set manual IP configuration(main router default gateway and also DNS )   for your laptop Wifi connection and probably it will work.